# from data.table to matrix and fill missing transitions with 0

Tags: r

I have data that look like this:

```
dt = data.table(from = c('a','a','b','b','c','c','c','d'), to = c('c','d','a','c','a','b','d','c'), value = c(1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10))
> dt
   from to value
1:    a  c     1
2:    a  d     2
3:    b  a     4
4:    b  c     6
5:    c  a     7
6:    c  c     8
7:    c  d     9
8:    d  c    10
```

I would like to turn this into a matrix where `from` becomes the row names, `to` is the column names and the resulting cells are filled by `value`.

Where there are no rows in `dt` for a given `from` & `to` combination, I'd like it filled by `0` in the matrix. So the **ideal result would look like this**:

```
  a b  c d
a 0 0  1 2
b 4 0  6 0
c 7 8  0 9
d 0 0 10 0
```

The closest I could come to is this, which unfortunately repeats the values.

```
> matrix(dt$value, nrow = length(unique(dt$from)), ncol = length(unique(dt$to)), byrow = T,
+        dimnames = list(sort(unique(dt$from)),
+                        sort(unique(dt$to))))
  a b c  d
a 1 2 4  6
b 7 8 9 10
c 1 2 4  6
d 7 8 9 10
```

How can I edit this so that instead of the values being repeated, empty spaces (i.e. combinations of `from` and `to` that do not exist in `dt` are filled with `0`)?

Comment: `xtabs(value ~ from + to, data = dt)`

Comment: oh yes, my bad. thank you!